# How to pass multiple values to one parameter in django rest api url for response?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

We have created one django restapi for GET response, for this url is like this 
127.0.0.1:8000/candidate/api/smarttest?package_id=1&chapter_id=1&level_type=easy

in above url we are only passing one id for those,bur we want to pass multiple ids to one parameter i.e chapter_id=[1,2,3] like this we want to pass

For this how can we pass,here is my code

I have tried with this code

```
def get(self,request):
    try:
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        response_dict={"status":True,"data":{}}
        package_id = request.GET['package_id']
        chapter_id = request.GET['chapter_id']
        level_type= request.GET.get('complex_id', '0')

        complexity_dict = {
            'easy': [1,2,3,4,5],
            'medium': [6,7,8,9,10]
        }

        question_set = QuestionSet.objects.filter(
            pkg_id__pk=package_id, chapter__pk=chapter_id
        )

        ibs_object = IbsTable.objects.filter(
            ibs_question_setmap__set_id__in=question_set,                           
            complexity__in=complexity_dict.get(level_type,range(0,11))
        )

        v_pks = [qq.pk for qq in ibs_object]
        data = SetContentDetails().splitting(request,v_pks)

        response_dict['data'] = data

    except Exception as e:
        ieonline_except_logger.critical(
            'candidate_management \t index \t '
            + str(e) 
            + '\n'
            + str(traceback.format_exc())
        )
        response_dict = {"status": False, "msg": Exception}
    return Response(response_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

To obtain a list of the data with the requested key, use `QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)` (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)).

You code will be something like:

```
chapter_id = request.GET.getlist('chapter_id') # [1,2,3]
```

Then, pass the `chapter_id` list in your url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/candidate/api/smarttest?chapter_id=1&chapter_id=2&chapter_id=3
```